# Cant upload app on Play Store ( Pricing & Distribution error)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to add app on play store.It's my second app.There was no problem during uploading of my first app.
I've finished APK,Store Listing and Content Rating,but When I switch from navigation to Pricing and Distribution,on The top of the page there is red label with text "Failed to retrieve tax rates for local country prices. (//there is written some numbers)".After this Save draft button becomes unclickable. please help

Comment: Could you provide more details? is that appearing just when you enter the page or when you try to specify a price?

Comment: no,not specifying price.I want to add free app.When I click Pricing & Distribution The page is loading and When it's loaded,in top of page is written "Failed to retrieve tax rates for local country prices. (//there is written some numbers)"

Comment: I have the same issue. Here is a picture of how it looks for me: [http://imgur.com/VbVAIQ9](http://imgur.com/VbVAIQ9). I also can't seem to update my store listing any more (can't press save).

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a temporary support issue on someone's servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here. Just chatted with Google support - they reckon it is a bug on their side. They said they are working on it...