# Failed to retrieve tax rates for local country prices. (668269003)

Tags: android

Today, when you want to deploy the application in the Google Play store and upon arrival to the prices & app distribution emerge me this message

[image]

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Here's another more updated thread on the same topic:
[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196566/cant-upload-app-on-play-store-pricing-distribution-error/37197271)

Answer (score 2):

Same error here. So probably will be a temporal failure.

Answer (score 0):

It was a temporary issue. Just fixed by Google's team.